# File Management Server in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, svn, eclipse-plugin, client-server

I have an application(SWT) where i need to manage a file at the server end. By managing i mean 3 things, **writing** contents to the file, applying **read/write** lock mechanism to it and **displying** the same in the `TextArea`. I need to create a **multithreaded server** to achieve this as my application(which actually is a eclipse based plugin) accepts **multiple users**. I'm new to this client-server thing and socket programming and i've read few tutorials but still havent found any optimum solution to it. I do not need the code(there are plenty on the internet), rather i need the way or the steps to do it. 
Thanks.

Also, i found some server code which actually works fine. However not displaying the desired results.

**What i rellay want to do with this file is to maintain the author's name. revision number and related destils as the SVN do on the server side.**

Server Program:

```
public void onServer() throws Exception {
        String sentByClient;
        String line1 = null;
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        while(true) {

    System.out.println("Listening...");
        Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        sentByClient = inFromClient.readLine();

        System.out.println("Received: " + sentByClient);

        File file=new File("HistoryFile.txt");//------------------server file
        BufferedWriter writ=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writ.write(sentByClient);
        writ.close();
        BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while((line1=read.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line1);

        }
        outToClient.writeBytes(line1);

                    }

    }
```

Client code:

```
public void onClient(String param) throws Exception {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
          DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
          //sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
          sentence=param; // Here i'm sending the author name, revision details, etc from svn to my server 
          outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
          newSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
          System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + newSentence);
          historyArea.append(newSentence);
    }
```

What i actually need is maintaining a file on the server and displaying the file contents on the textArea(historyArea). I'm sending the history data from SVN to the file.

Desired Ouptut:

```
Revision Number: 1
Author: a
Time:xxxx
Changed Path:xxxx 
-------------------
Revision Number: 2
Author: a
Time:xxxx
Changed Path:xxxx
------------------
Revision Number: 3
Author: a
Time:xxxx
Changed Path:xxxx
```

Ouptut i'm getting is just the first revision:

```
Revision Number: 1
    Author: a
    Time:xxxx
    Changed Path:xxxx
```

Comment: In onClient(), print out 'param' and check whether you are actually sending the right data or not. I think the problem is in the code that calls onClient().

Comment: @NandakishoreK Yes, may be that's the reason, as i've mentioned  in the code that it prints the data sent by the server, there's no such thing in the output(at client side), have to recheck the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this line

```
BufferedWriter writ=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

you are opening the file in write mode, so a write operation will overwrite the existing contents.
Instead do this

```
BufferedWriter writ=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
```

This will open the file in append mode.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, still it didint solve the problem...server still not recvng the complete log details.Only the first revision shows up