# File management client-server programming

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm stuck with this client-server programming, where i want the server to maintain a file, which stores the data sent by the client. The code is as follows:

Client Side:

```
public class ClientSide {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        String sentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');            
        clientSocket.close();
}
}
```

Server Side:

```
public class ServerSide {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file=new File("s1.txt");
            ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(6789);

            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);

            bos.close();
            sock.close();

            BufferedReader write=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while((line=write.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

     }
}
```

Now, as the user is sending data to server, for example '**Vinayak**' is the data sent to the server, only the first character i.e. '**V**' is written to the file. I must be missing out something in the code and i cant find it out. Also, i've asked similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075467/file-management-server-in-java) however, couldnt get the desired result

Comment: Try calling flush on the input stream before writing the readsByte to the file output stream. Hope it helps!

Comment: @JunedAhsan i guess InputStream cannot be flushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the read operation has actually read as many bytes as you wanted at the server end. See the [javadocs for InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

...

> The read(b, off, len) method for class InputStream simply calls the method read() repeatedly. If the first such call results in an IOException, that exception is returned from the call to the read(b, off, len) method. If any subsequent call to read() results in a IOException, the exception is caught and treated as if it were end of file; the bytes read up to that point are stored into b and the number of bytes read before the exception occurred is returned

Change your server reading code to be in a loop:

```
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(bytesRead);
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Output on server side:

```
1
85
9
9
    ...
5
10
8
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum facilisis nulla id aliquet. Suspendisse venenatis condimentum erat adipiscing interdum. Etiam aliquet iaculis mauris lacinia lacinia. Morbi nec nisi est. Duis vel nunc a risus scelerisque feugiat. Morbi eget odio ac arcu vehicula facilisis vel ut nibh. Morbi sodales tristique ante eu aliquam. Ut a leo nisi. Morbi eu purus sed lectus mattis tincidunt.
```

Comment: it also says "The read(b, off, len) method for class InputStream simply calls the method read() repeatedly" well, when  i'm debugging the code, it only read the first character i.e. value of bytesRead=1